# Intent putExtra bitmap issue

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
   ((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.fish)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(StartupActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(NAME_EXTRA, ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString().trim());
            intent.putExtra(TYPE_EXTRA, FishTypes.FISH.toString());
            intent.putExtra(WORLD_TYPE_EXTRA, worldType);
            intent.putExtra(LOGO_EXTRA, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

If I start activity and click on ImageButton it send me to the same Activity I was before (StartupActivity). However if I comment out the last putExtra like this:

```
//intent.putExtra(LOGO_EXTRA, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo));
```

Then it works fine. It sends me to the GameActivity as I want. What could be the problem?

**EDIT**

My GameActivity looks like this:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

public static GamePanel gamePanel;
public static String name;
public static FishTypes type;
public static String worldType;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    requestWindowFeature(getWindow().FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    name = getIntent().getStringExtra(StartupActivity.NAME_EXTRA);
    type = FishTypes.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra(StartupActivity.TYPE_EXTRA));
    worldType = getIntent().getStringExtra(StartupActivity.WORLD_TYPE_EXTRA);

    gamePanel = new GamePanel(this);
    //gamePanel.bitmaps.put("logo", (Bitmap)getIntent().getParcelableExtra(StartupActivity.LOGO_EXTRA));
    setContentView(gamePanel);

    if(!StartupActivity.isNetworkAvailable()) {
        Toast.makeText(StartupActivity.getInstance(), "You have no internet connection...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if(gamePanel.client != null)
        gamePanel.client.disconnect();
    StartupActivity.getInstance().reopen();
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

What I want to achieve is preloading this bitmap in StartupActivity and then just send it to the GameActivity to the GamePanel and then draw it on the canvas as a loading image. I can't load this image in GameActivity because it will be late to show it. Do you understand?

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo)

it is not need you can access drawable in your application at global level

Comment: and can you tell me how?

Comment: you want your logo in GameActivity.class?

Comment: please put game activity here

Comment: It is better to pass Drawable as integer beside using BitmapFactory..
intent.putExtra(LOGO_EXTRA, R.drawable.logo);

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, there is an `Intent` payload limit, as far as I know there is a limit of **1MB**, but in some cases can be **500kb**. If this limit is overreached the app will crash, in your case crashed and restarted.

Second of all, `Bundle` and `Intent` are used to send small amount of data to `Activity` and `Fragments`, usually some configs/params so that the activity/fragment will know how to build itself.

Third, is a really bad practice to pass around instances of bitmaps, you need just a second of distraction to create a huge leak in your app, that will cost you a lot of time to find and fix it.

Now the solution for you is really simple. You can pass the `id` of the bitmap you want to use in the next activity.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(StartupActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(NAME_EXTRA, ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString().trim());
        intent.putExtra(TYPE_EXTRA, FishTypes.FISH.toString());
        intent.putExtra(WORLD_TYPE_EXTRA, worldType);
        intent.putExtra(LOGO_EXTRA,  R.drawable.logo); // R.drawable.logo is actually an int.
        startActivity(intent);
```

In your `GameActivity`

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(...)
    int myAwesomeDrawable = getIntent().getExtra(LOGO_EXTRA, 0); // 0 is default value in case nothing is added to the key
    if(myAwesomeDrawable != 0){ // safety check
      imageView.setImageResource(myAwesomeDrawable);
      // or do whatever you like with it.
    }
```

Comment: Nearly the same I wrote before. Until I realized, R.drawable.logo can be accessed in the target activity anyway. This is why you don't need to pass the logo at all as an extra.

Comment: But I need it to preload in the StartupActivity... this answer is wrong. I don't want to load it in GameActivity because it will take time to load and it should be the loading image. Understand?

Comment: @duri Loading an image from assets doesn't take time is almost instant.